# offset didn't work along with update_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I got some data, like this: `book.pages`

I want to update some of the pages, my code looks like this:

```
book.pages.offset(1).update_all(updated_at: Time.now)
```

I thought all the pages of the book other than the first page would be updated. However the result is all the pages including the first one got updated.

I am very confused. May anybody explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell offset does nothing in a mysql update.  You can use a limit but I don't think that will help in your case.

If you really need to do this try this line:

```
book.pages.where('id != ?', book.pages.first.id).update_all(updated_at: Time.now)
```

You could also do this manually with a mysql statement but it would be painful.  Something like:

```
Book.connection.execute(%[
  UPDATE book_pages
  INNER JOIN books ON books.id = book_pages.book_id
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, book_id, MIN(book_pages.id) FROM book_pages GROUP BY book_id
  ) as bp ON bp.book_id = book_pages.id
  WHERE book_pages.id != bp.id && books.id == #{book.id}
])
```